# XML Beans - Update and Save the XML document Object

Tags: java, xml

I have to Update the Xml document object generated using Apache XMLbeans.There are two ways I am trying to update and save the document.

Step 1 : I am parsing the document and updating with the new values and saving with the parsed document itself.

```
private boolean updateContact(ContactType contacts, String contactFilePath, String name) throws Exception { 
    ContactsDocument contactDoc = ContactsDocument.Factory.parse(new File(contactFilePath));
    ContactType contact = contactDoc.getContactType();
    contact.setName(name);

    contactDoc.save(new File(contactFilePath) , XmlUtils.getDefaultFileSavingOptions());
}
```

Step 2 : I am passing the updated document type and creating new instance of the xml document and saving with the updated type.

```
private boolean writeContact(ContactType contactType, String contactFilePath) throws Exception { 
    ContactsDocument contactsDoc = ContactsDocument.Factory.newInstance();
    contactsDoc.setContactType(contactType);
    contactsDoc.save(new File(contactFilePath), XmlUtils.getDefaultFileSavingOptions());
}
```

The step 2 is working but i want to know, will step 1 work ? and which is the efficient way of doing it for this scenario.

Comment: Also will the "contactDoc.save(new File(contactFilePath) , XmlUtils.getDefaultFileSavingOptions()); " with XML default file saving options override or remove If the XML file already has some namespaces.     This is what my default options XmlOptions fileSaveOptions = new XmlOptions();
        fileSaveOptions.setSavePrettyPrint();
        fileSaveOptions.setSavePrettyPrintIndent(4);
        fileSaveOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces();
        fileSaveOptions.setUseDefaultNamespace();

Answer (score 0):

The **Step 1** works perfect with the XML default file saving options and it does not modifies or removes any of the existing namespaces present in the file.

```
private boolean updateContact(ContactType contacts, String contactFilePath, String name) throws Exception { 
    ContactsDocument contactDoc = ContactsDocument.Factory.parse(new File(contactFilePath));
    ContactType contact = contactDoc.getContactType();
    contact.setName(name);

    contactDoc.save(new File(contactFilePath) , XmlUtils.getDefaultFileSavingOptions());
}
```

It is also good approach to parse the file and save the changes on top of it, Instead of parse and instantiating the xml document for every updates.